# Java3D-How do you get the coordinates of a Shape3D intersection?

Tags: java, java-3d

So I'm new to any sort of 3d programming, and I'm essentially using Java3d to create mathematical models in 3D space.

Anyways, suppose I have 2 Shape3d objects. How would I go about finding the exact coordinates of each intersection point? I looked here ([Java 3D: Get intersection of two Shape3D's?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8463833/java-3d-get-intersection-of-two-shape3ds)) to get the following code:

`Bounds quadArrayBounds = quadArrayShape.getBounds();
if (quadArrayBounds.intersect(new Point3d(startLine.x, startLine.y, startLine.z), 
new Vector3d(endLine.x, endLine.y, endLine.z))){
               // Action to do if Intesect is true
 }`

but I'm pretty sure this method can only find one intersection point. What should I do? Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: This code will detect a single intersection with a single *ray*, but only with the *bounds* of the object, and not with the object itself. The crucial question is: How should the result of such an intersection look like? For triangle meshes, it could possibly be a long list of (Edge,Triangle) pairs, containing each edge of one shape that intersects a triangle of the other shape (but in which order?) For quad meshes, it may be even more difficult. In any case, you *might* have to do these tests on your own. J3D has limited (API-level) support for collision detection on the level of primitives.

Comment: Alright thanks. Not sure if it's worth the trouble to test intersections on my owm. I may end up switching to JMonkey simply because J3D seems ridiculously limited in what it can do.

Comment: Maybe you should look at my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25727944/458157 JMonkeyEngine, JogAmp's Ardor3D Continuation and LibGDX are nice alternatives.